# How to Search Replace when filename URLs are different

Tags: replace, notepad++

I want to search-replace a line that contains different addresses but I just want to search-replace a specific portion. Like

Search: < img border="0" src="*http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-OKZyRpnFLgw/UtqngoauEwI/AAAAAAADOlM/aXCJiiTRkaM/***s1600**/*005.JPG*"/ >

Replace: < img border="0" src="*http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-OKZyRpnFLgw/UtqngoauEwI/AAAAAAADOlM/aXCJiiTRkaM/***s420**/*005.JPG*"/ >

I just want to change the bold text. The Italic text changes in every file address.

I cant just simply search replace s1600 with s420 because it changes many other entries, I just want to make this change if it appears in **< img** address.

Help!

Answer (score 1):

Using a **Find what** of `(< img[^>]*?)s1600` and a **Replace with** of `\1s420` will work on the line you give; you should have **Regular expression** selected. It will replace a *single* occurrence of `s1600` between an `< img` and the next `>`. If you expect two or more `s1600` between the strings then run the replace multiple times.

The **Find what** may not be strict enough. If text such as `pqrs1600` or `s160000` should not be altered then you could try `(< img[^>]*?)\bs1600\b`.

If the `s1600` always occurs between a `*` and a `\` as in the example then the **Find what** may be better as `(< img[^>]*?\*)s1600/` and then the  **Replace with** should be `\1s420/`.

The basic idea in each case is to match the text that identifies where the item is and to capture that text using the round braces. The `[^>]*?` matches zero or more characters that are not a `>`, the `*?` parts indicates a non-greedy match, so it matches the smallest sequence possible before the next part of the regular expression.

Comment: I appreciate your help. But it didn't work. Question I posted above did not include some codes.

Actual code is

`<a href="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-occTaO-Gy1Y/Ut1haLgJshI/AAAAAAADO-I/QvZp1HGTV_g/s1600/Urban-Studio-New-Western-wear-dresses-2014-for-winter-3.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-occTaO-Gy1Y/Ut1haLgJshI/AAAAAAADO-I/QvZp1HGTV_g/s1600/Urban-Studio-New-Western-wear-dresses-2014-for-winter-3.jpg"/></a>`

I just want to replace s1600 (that appears inside img tag only) with s420. Please help

Comment: @Zohaib you should edit your question to give your actual problem. My answer works for the example you first gave. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service, it aims to help you understand your problems and solve them yourself. What have you tried? What variations of my answer have you tried? What effect did they have and what have you learned? When you say "it didn't work" what did it do?